# Noop primitive operations

Tags: flutter, dart

I recently upgraded my flutter to 3.7 and I got this error all over my project

```
Noop primitive operations





ListView.builder(
                  key: Key('builder ${selected.toString()}'), //attention
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 22),
                  itemCount: widget.faq.length,
                  itemBuilder: (final BuildContext context, final int index) => listItems(widget.faq[index], index),
                )
```

The error is on toString method.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly a linter error indicating that the call `toString` is unnecessary.  You are already interpolating - have you considered removing  `toString()`